# Lodash filtering/intersection of two object arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have two arrays of objects. In the second array, you can assign an id from the first array. How can I filter the first array to only show results if its id has not been associated in array2? I have tried a nested filter of a filter in lodash, and a filter of a find, but it's just not working.

Here is what I have tried:

array1.filter(item => item.id === find(array2, { associatedID: item.id })[0].associatedID) Second iteration of finding inside a filter. I tried a similar filter approach instead of find, but that did not work either. Is there an issue with using the item.id inside the find function, as its provided from the parent filter param? or no?

Help?

```
const array1 = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Test 1"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Test 2",
}
{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "Test 3",
}
]

const array2 = [{
  "id": "12",
  "name": "Test 1",
  "associatedID": "1"
},
{
  "id": "22",
  "name": "Test 2",
  "associatedID": "2"
}
{
  "id": "32",
  "name": "Test 3",
}
]
```

Comment: Rather than asking us to write the code from scratch, please share what you've already tried.

Comment: Please update the question with the requested information instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 4):

The non performant approach would be

```
array1.filter(elm1 => {
  return array2.find(elm2 => elm2.associatedID === elm1).length === 1
})
```

If your arrays are big, you could sort both arrays according to id and associatedID and run a for loop on both of them to somehow return result

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash's [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceWith) to get all items from `array` that don't have an `associatedID` in `array2`:

```js
const array1 =[{"id":"1","name":"Test 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2"},{"id":"3","name":"Test 3"}]

const array2 = [{"id":"12","name":"Test 1","associatedID":"1"},{"id":"22","name":"Test 2","associatedID":"2"},{"id":"32","name":"Test 3"}]

const result = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, 
  ({ id }, { associatedID }) => id === associatedID
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.filter` and `Array.some` to get the items from `array1` not associated with `array2`:

```js
const array1 = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Test 1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Test 2", }, { "id": "3", "name": "Test 3", } ]
const array2 = [{ "id": "12", "name": "Test 1", "associatedID": "1" }, { "id": "22", "name": "Test 2", "associatedID": "2" }, { "id": "32", "name": "Test 3", } ]

const result = array1.filter(x => !array2.some(y => y.associatedID == x.id))
console.log(result)
```

With lodash this can be done also via [_.differenceWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceWith):

```js
const array1 = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Test 1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Test 2", }, { "id": "3", "name": "Test 3", } ]
const array2 = [{ "id": "12", "name": "Test 1", "associatedID": "1" }, { "id": "22", "name": "Test 2", "associatedID": "2" }, { "id": "32", "name": "Test 3", } ]

const result = _.differenceWith(array1, array2, (x,y) => x.id === y.associatedID)
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```